# Scripts : what's the difference between exec file.js and js file.js?

Tags: javascript

[The doc](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#non-interactive-use-jsre-script-mode) says that scripts can be executed with : `geth --exec 'loadscript("script.js")' attach`, but in the [example script](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contracts-and-Transactions#example-script) they give right after, they say to use `geth js script.js 2>>geth.log`.

What is the difference between the two ?

Comment: I believe those are two ways of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference [this document](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) for most of your Geth command line needs.

```
  --exec value           Execute JavaScript statement (only in combination with console/attach)
```

Comment: Thank you ! Any ideas what the 2 in `2>>geth.log` means ? I still have a lot of blur around javascript execution. How do I pass arguments (can I) ? How do I return values ? Why are a lot of commands of the js console not authorized in scripts, and which one are authorized exactly ? The only doc I managed to find around scripts explicitly is the very long example script, with no explanation at all. Do you know anywhere I could find more detailed help ?